# RabbitMq with docker c#

Tags: c#, docker, rabbitmq

i have a problem with rabbitmq queues in docker. when i run the project normally via dotnet run everything works fine but when i run the project via docker i get an error :

```
dateapp-container  | Unhandled exception. RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
dateapp-container  |  ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
dateapp-container  |  ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
```

my config:

docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dateapp
    environment: 
       - RABBIT_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal
        
    container_name: dateapp-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/DateApp/DateApp.Application/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7141:7141
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Receiver

```
 var rabbitHostName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RABBIT_HOSTNAME");

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = rabbitHostName ?? "localhost",
                UserName = "guest",
                Password = "guest"
            };
```

the current method works, however, the error above appears when:

enter in HostName localhost and I want to run the project as docker

type in hostname host.docker.internal and want to run the project by dotnet run

**my main question is is it possible to write the code other than to do HostName = rabbitHostName ?? "localhost",**

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose creates a bridge network that the containers are connected to. They can communicate using the service names as host names.

Since they can communicate in this way, there's no need to expose ports unless you want them to be reachable from the host. In your case, you can probably remove the mapping of port 5672 if you only need to reach RabbitMQ from the API container.

You then end up with something like this

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq-data:/var/lib/rabbitmq

  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dateapp
    environment: 
       - RABBIT_HOSTNAME=rabbitmq
        
    container_name: dateapp-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/DateApp/DateApp.Application/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7141:7141
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

Please note that `depends_on` only waits for the container to be started. There's no guarantee that RabbitMQ is ready to accept connections when your API container is started. You need to code your program in a way that it can handle this situation.

Comment: ok i did as you say and change HostName on "localhost" and effect is the same. display error.

Comment: To see if it's because the API starts before RabbitMQ is ready to accept connections, can you do `docker compose up -d rabbitmq`, wait 30 seconds and then do `docker compose up -d`?